# Cannot disable gate keeper

Tags: gatekeeper

I received my M1 Mac Mini a couple weeks ago and restored my time machine backup from an Intel Mac with Catalina.

Today I execute this command: `sudo spctl --master-disable` and the following occurred.

```
objc[865]: Class SPExecutionPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class AppWrapper is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class AppWrapperPolicyResult is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class AppWrapperPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class SPLog is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class MIS is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class SPExecutionHistoryItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class SPExecutionPolicyItem is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class SPDeveloperPolicy is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[865]: Class GKScanResult is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemPolicy.framework/Versions/A/SystemPolicy and /usr/sbin/spctl. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I've never seen such messages in previous versions of Mac OS. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Not sure, but are you changing/replacing system files? Because doing this is more difficult under Big Sur than on previous macOS systems. There’s a new system volume structure that separates system files from the user’s data. To make changes to system files you have to unseal this system volume, mount it, make changes to the system files and then reseal it. I’m not sure how to do this but you should investigate how the new SSV works.

Comment: From what operating system are you trying to execute `spctl` ? Most boot modes it’s to check status and not change anything by design. https://support.apple.com/en-gu/guide/security/sec7703b1423/1/web/1 (and all those messages are harmless - the system developers need to fix them )

Comment: It's the M1 so Big Sur is the only OS for now...and I'm not changing any system file...I guess!?

I'm doing this is because I downloaded an app but it says the app is damaged. Someone on stackexchange mentioned I should try disabling gate keeper using the command.

Comment: There are better ways of getting the app to launch without disabling all of Gatekeeper. It's also possible that the app IS damaged.

Answer (score 5):

U need to see if the spctl is actually disabled though.

I noticed same wordy warnings when I tried same command. In my case it was disabled and the same warnings keep showing up no matter what spctl command is run for me.

- To disable Gatekeeper, use `sudo spctl --global-disable`.
- To re-enable Gatekeeper, use `sudo spctl --global-enable`.
- To verify the status, use `sudo spctl --status`.

In versions older than macOS 10.15.7, use `sudo spctl --master-disable` instead.

Last line after the warnings should be:

```
assessments disabled
```

So, the command worked for me to disable and enable spctl.

Regarding those warnings stack overflow user [bbum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25646/bbum) claims to [wrote the error reporting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581884/class-is-implemented-in-both-one-of-the-two-will-be-used), but so far there is no explanation why the warnings are reporting on this command.